# SQL Synatax error for datetime column

Tags: sql, sqlite

The structure of history is

```
CREATE TABLE 'history' 
         ( 
                      'id'     INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement NOT NULL, 
                      'symbol' INTEGER NOT NULL, 
                      'shares' INTEGER NOT NULL, 
                      'price' text NOT NULL, 
                      'transaction' datetime NOT NULL, 
                      'user_id'     INTEGER NOT NULL 
         )
```

The insert sql statement fails on:

```
INSERT INTO history 
        (symbol, 
         shares, 
         price, 
         transaction, 
         user_id) 
VALUES   ('MSFT', 
         10, 
         25, 
         '2017-02-26 21:50:10', 
         3)
```

Could not fix the issue. Please help.

Comment: can you post the error message as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`transaction` is a [reserved word](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) so you should double quote it when you want to use it as a column name:

```
INSERT INTO history
(symbol, shares, price, "transaction", user_id) ...
                        ^           ^
```

Better would be to use a different name for the column so that you don't have to worry about quoting things.

Also, in SQL, double quotes are for identifiers and single quotes are for string literals so you should get in the habit of using double quotes in your `create table`. SQLite will let you get away with a lot of things but good habits (such as proper quoting) are better than bad habits (such as relying on SQLite's sloppy interpretation of SQL).